# Как скрыть цену 0 через JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, opencart

Помогите скрыть цену значение 0 на товаре, как сделать так что бы 0 не отображался? Вот ссылка на сайт, https://iltech.kz/telefony-i-gadzhety/smartfony?page=4

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
let price = document.querySelectorAll('.us-module-price-actual');
for (let i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
        price[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос или ссылку на сайте. Тут нет гадалок.

Answer (score 1):

Вы скрываете первый элемент в списке, i === 0, а вам нужно прочитать значение поля и сравнить его со значением, примерно так, price[i] === "00.0 тг"